Getting null pointer exception when trying to make authnrequest using spring security saml
`I am trying to generate a authn request without using spring boot and only using spring-security-saml2-service-provider. When I try to marshall the authnRequest I am getting error as
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: org.opensaml.core.xml.io.MarshallingException: No marshaller available for {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion}Issuer, child of {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol}AuthnRequest at org.opensamlExample.SecurityConfiguration.serialize(SecurityConfiguration.java:116) at org.opensamlExample.SecurityConfiguration.generateAuthRequest(SecurityConfiguration.java:91) at org.opensamlExample.SecurityConfiguration.main(SecurityConfiguration.java:81) Caused by: org.opensaml.core.xml.io.MarshallingException: No marshaller available for {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion}Issuer, child of {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol}AuthnRequest at org.opensaml.core.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshallChildElements(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:270) at org.opensaml.core.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshallInto(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:219) at org.opensaml.core.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:121) at org.opensaml.saml.common.AbstractSAMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractSAMLObjectMarshaller.java:58) at org.opensaml.core.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:76) at org.opensamlExample.SecurityConfiguration.serialize(SecurityConfiguration.java:110) ... 2 more
Based on my understanding and some google search, I am trying to learn saml integration for my project. This is the code I have so far, I am getting error when trying to marshal the authnrequest. Not sure what i am doing wrong.
Code:
public static AuthnRequest buildAuthRequest() {
    RandomIdentifierGenerationStrategy securerandomgenerator = new RandomIdentifierGenerationStrategy();
    AuthnRequestBuilder builder  = new AuthnRequestBuilder();
    AuthnRequest request= builder.buildObject();
    request.setAssertionConsumerServiceURL("http://localhost:8080/samlResponse");
    request.setDestination("https://dev-omtekjsu50kzoy13.us.auth0.com/samlp/HuW59mrq3kiGZBmvP9ZdZLil8qIL4o0y");
    request.setProtocolBinding(SAMLConstants.SAML2_POST_BINDING_URI);
    request.setID(securerandomgenerator.generateIdentifier());
    // build issuer
    Issuer issuer = new IssuerBuilder().buildObject();
    issuer.setValue("https://mySamlExampleSP.com:8080");
    request.setIssuer(issuer);
    
    //build nameid policy
    NameIDPolicy nameIDPolicy = new NameIDPolicyBuilder().buildObject();
    nameIDPolicy.setAllowCreate(false);
    nameIDPolicy.setFormat(NameIDType.TRANSIENT);
    request.setNameIDPolicy(nameIDPolicy);
    
    MessageContext context = new MessageContext();
    context.setMessage(request);
    SAMLPeerEntityContext peerEntityContext = context.getSubcontext(SAMLPeerEntityContext.class, true);
    SAMLEndpointContext endpointContext = peerEntityContext.getSubcontext(SAMLEndpointContext.class, true);
    return request;
    //endpointContext.setEndpoint();
}

public static AuthnRequest initializeOpensaml() {
    OpenSamlInitializationService.initialize();
    AuthnRequest request = buildAuthRequest();
    return request;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AuthnRequest request=initializeOpensaml();
 generateAuthRequest(request);
}

public static void generateAuthRequest(AuthnRequest authnRequest) {
    RelyingPartyRegistration registration = RelyingPartyRegistrations.fromMetadataLocation("classpath:asserting-party-metadata.xml")
            .registrationId("samlExample")
            .singleLogoutServiceResponseLocation("{baseUrl}/logout/saml2/slo")
            .nameIdFormat("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient")
            .build();
    Saml2RedirectAuthenticationRequest  authenticationRequest= Saml2RedirectAuthenticationRequest.withRelyingPartyRegistration(registration)
            .samlRequest(serialize(authnRequest)).
            id(authnRequest.getID()).
            build();
}

private static String serialize(AuthnRequest authnRequest) {
    try {
        XMLObjectProviderRegistry xmlObjectProviderRegistry = new XMLObjectProviderRegistry();
        ConfigurationService.register(XMLObjectProviderRegistry.class, xmlObjectProviderRegistry);
        xmlObjectProviderRegistry.setParserPool(getParserPool());
        Marshaller  marshallObj = xmlObjectProviderRegistry.getMarshallerFactory().getMarshaller(authnRequest);
        AuthnRequestMarshaller marshaller = new AuthnRequestMarshaller();
        Element element =marshaller.marshall(authnRequest); // Getting null marshaller here...
        String xml =SerializeSupport.nodeToString(element);
        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return encoded;
    }
    catch (MarshallingException ex) {
        throw new Saml2Exception(ex);
    }
}

I have initialized and again I was trying to create a new XMLObjectProviderRegistry ConfigurationService and add those details also, so it was not working, When I removed below lines I don't get the error any more.
XMLObjectProviderRegistry xmlObjectProviderRegistry = new 
  XMLObjectProviderRegistry();
            ConfigurationService.register(XMLObjectProviderRegistry.class, xmlObjectProviderRegistry);
            xmlObjectProviderRegistry.setParserPool(getParserPool());
            Marshaller  marshallObj = xmlObjectProviderRegistry.getMarshallerFactory().getMarshaller(authnRequest);


Perhaps it would be useful to add some more context, or show the code where you are trying to marshall the authnRequest.

I have edited the code, but I think I found the issue. I was initializing and again I was creating a new XMLObjectProviderRegistry ConfigurationService etc. Removing those lines fixed my problems.
